# Flutter: How to get a pop value when the original target page has been replaced?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Let's say I have three pages, A, B and C.

From page A I have a `FloatingActionButton` to navigate to page B with a `then()` statement for the return value. If the return value equals `false` nothing happens, in any other case page A will be refreshed:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(B.routeName).then((value){
      if (value != false){
        _refresh(); // My own function to refresh page A
      }
    });
  },
  ...
)
```

In page B, I have a `Scaffold` with just a background screen and a `FloatingButton`. The button leads to page C, while clicking on the screen will lead back to page A, without refresh necessary.

```
Scaffold(
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
    },
    ...
  ),
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(C.routeName);
    },
    ...
  ),
)
```

My problem is that when I click the floating action button to go to page C, page B pops, and page A gets null value in its `then()` statement.

How do I avoid page B popping, and 'link' the return value in the `then()` statement from page A to the value of `pop()` statement from page C instead of B?

The real problem here is that page A will not refresh when I pop page C, as its `then()` has already triggered by page B, not the fact that it refreshed when page B pops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in page B instead of **pushReplacementNamed** you can **just push** and await for result in page c then when it returned value you can pop to page A,
in page B you can write:

```
  onPressed: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(C.routeName).then((value){
  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
});
```

},

Comment: Nice! It did the trick. The pop value in B needed to be the same as the pop value in C, but it worked well! Thank you